# Understanding fgetc program

Tags: c, file

I'm reading a book about c programming and don't understand a shown example. Or more precisely I don't understand why it works because I would think it shouldn't.

The code is simple, it reads the content of a text file and outputs it in output area. As far as I understand it, I would think that the

```
 ch = fgetc(stream);
```

ought to be inside the while loop, because it only reads one int a time? and needs to read the next int after the current one has been outputted. Well, it turns out that this code indeed works fine so I hope someone could explain my fallacy to me. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *stream;
    char filename[67];
    int ch;
    printf("Please enter the filename?\n");
    gets(filename);
    if((stream = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening the file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    ch = fgetc(stream);
    while (!feof(stream)) {
        putchar(ch);
        ch = fgetc(stream);
    }

    fclose(stream);
}
```

Comment: This is not good quality code. As you can see in answers, you can avoid `feof` at all. Still, using `feof` there is no need to use two `fgetc`: it whould  be enough `while (!feof(stream)) putchar(fgetc(stream));`

Comment: Actually, this code will fail outputing one byte streams!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the answers, I wish I could accept all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confuse because of feof():

Doc: [`int feof ( FILE * stream );`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/feof/)

> Checks whether the end-of-File indicator associated with stream is
>   set, returning a value different from zero if it is.
>
> This **indicator is generally set by a previous operation** on the stream
>   that attempted to read at or past the end-of-file.

```
   ch = fgetc(stream);      <---"Read current symbol from file"
    while (!feof(stream)) { <---"Check EOF read/returned by last fgetc() call"
        putchar(ch);        <---"Output lasts read symbol, that was not EOF"
        ch = fgetc(stream); <---"Read next symbols from file"
    }
   <-- control reach here when EOF found
```

A much better way is to write your loop like:

```
while((ch = fgetc(stream))!= EOF){ <--" Read while EOF not found"
   putchar(ch);   <-- "inside loop print a symbol that is not EOF"
}
```

Additionally, Note: [`int fgetc ( FILE * stream );`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetc/)

> Returns the character currently pointed by the internal file position
>   indicator of the specified stream. The internal file position
>   indicator is then advanced to the next character.
>
> **If the stream is at the end-of-file when called, the function returns
>   EOF** and sets the end-of-file indicator for the stream (feof).
>
> If **a read error occurs**, the **function returns EOF** and sets the error
>   indicator for the stream (ferror).

Comment: @LS_dev which code? the code I given `better way is??`: I am pretty sure it will not fail, atleast in normal circumstances for any size of file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort in explaining everything, very helpful!

Comment: Correction, last character from ANY file will not be outputted! You read last character => pointer will be at end-of-file => !feof will be false => last character will not be outputted.

Comment: @LinusAn Your welcome!, you should read  [“while( !feof( file ) )” is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong?lq=1) Avoid using feof()

Comment: Thank you for the link! While reading the details your answer again and again, a question crossed my mind: fgetc reads characters as well as numbers, right? Why is fgetc returning int and still able to read characters like 'a'? Thank you!

Comment: @LinusAn its very good question. it returns a int, because EOF file is int type. from file it read a char. Wait I give you a very good link

Comment: @LinusAn Read: [Definition of EOF and how to use it effectively](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?id=1043284351&answer=1048865140)

Comment: Thanks for the link, very helpful! Wow, I didn't know how tricky that code is.

Answer (score 2):

If the `fgetc` outside `while` is removed, like this:

```
while (!feof(stream)) {
    putchar(ch);
    ch = fgetc(stream);
}
```

`ch` will be un-initialized the first time `putchar(ch)` is called.

By the way, don't use `gets`, because it may cause buffer overflow. Use `fgets` or `gets_s` instead. `gets` is removed in C11.

Comment: @LS_dev No, when saying that `gets` may cause buffer overflow, it's because it has no idea of the size of the buffer. `fgets` doesn't have this problem, see http://c-faq.com/stdio/getsvsfgets.html

Answer (score 2):

The code you have provided has 'ch =fgetc(stream);' before the While loop and  also 
'ch = fgetc(stream);' within the body of the loop.
It would be logical that the statement within the loop is retrieving the ch from the stream one at a time as you correctly state.

Answer (score 1):

It is inside and outside as you see. The one outside is responsible for reading the first character (which may be already the end of file, then the while wouldn't be entered anyway and nothing is printed), then it enters the loop, puts the character and reads the next one.. as long as the read character is not the end of file, the loop continues.

Answer (score 1):

`fgetc()` reads a `char(byte)` and return that byte,The reading of byte value depends on where the read pointer is available.

Once fgetc() successfully read one byte the read file pointer moves to the next byte .so if you read the file the `next byte` will be the output and it will continue upto it find the end of the file where it return EOF.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of second `fgetc` which is getting call upto `while (!feof(stream))`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this part here:

```
while (!feof(stream)) {
        putchar(ch);
        ch = fgetc(stream);
    }
```

is pretty unsafe and you should avoid checking EOF like that ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong) why).

The way you should read a file using `fgetc` is like so:

```
int ch;
while ((ch = fgetc(stream)) != EOF) 
{
   printf("%c", ch)
}
```

Comment: That whould be may choice if instead of `printf("%c",c)` you had `putchar(ch);`

Comment: Yea `putchar` is obviously fine too, I'm just more used to `printf` and the like.

Answer (score 1):

This is non functional code. Last character from file is never outputted. `fgetc` will read last character and pointer will be at end of file. So, when while is checked, `!feof` will return false, and read character will not be outputed.
`feof`is not preventing reading after end of file: for empty files `fgetc` will be called before `feof`!
Unless there is some benefit in console handling, two better options exist:
Using feof:

```
while (!feof(stream)) {
    ch=fgetc(stream);
    putchar(ch);
}
```

Without using `feof` - because `fgetc` returns `EOF` when there are no more characters:

```
while ((ch=fgetc(stream))!=EOF) putchar(ch);
```